# Stop and replay animation getting a same speed cause the outcome looks slow

Tags: jquery, animation

Currently I had one infinite loop animation, and that is a few element on the loop like box1, box2, box3, something like a rotating sushi.
When I click the box it will pop up something information and stop the animation, after 4 sec it will reanimate again.

But the problem I facing now is when after 4sec reanimate the speed looks very slow because of the animate duration.
Here is my code.

```
var timeoutBox;

$('.sushi_box').on('click', function(){

    $('.sushi_item').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    // here another code for stop the sushi roll.

    $('.total_roll').clearQueue().stop();

    // after 4 sec hide box;
    clearTimeout(timeoutBox);
    timeoutBox = setTimeout(function(){
        $('.sushi_item').removeClass('active');
        // here another code for reanimate the sushi roll.

        animateLoop();

    }, 4000)

})

function animateLoop(){

    var originWidth = $('.sushi_roll.origin').outerWidth(true);

    $('.total_roll').animate({ "left": -originWidth }, {
        easing:"linear", 
        duration:5000,
        complete: function(){

            $('.total_roll').css({ "left": 0});

            originNumber++;

            console.log(originNumber);

            if(originNumber == 1){

                console.log(1);
                var origin = $('.sushi_roll.origin').html();

                $('.sushi_roll.origin').remove();

                $('.total_roll').append('<div class="sushi_roll origin">'+origin+'</div>');

                var $sushiWidth   = $('.sushi_roll .sushi_item').outerWidth(true);
                var $sushiHeight  = $('.sushi_item').outerHeight(true);

                var $sushiOrginLength  = $('.sushi_roll.origin .sushi_item').length;
                var $sushiCloneLength  = $('.sushi_roll.clone .sushi_item').length;

                $('.sushi_roll.origin').css({ 
                    "width"  : $sushiOrginLength*$sushiWidth,
                    "height" : $sushiHeight 
                });

            } else if(originNumber == 2){

                console.log(2);
                var clone = $('.sushi_roll.clone').html();

                $('.sushi_roll.clone').remove();

                $('.total_roll').append('<div class="sushi_roll clone">'+clone+'</div>');

                var $sushiWidth   = $('.sushi_roll .sushi_item').outerWidth(true);
                var $sushiHeight  = $('.sushi_item').outerHeight(true);

                var $sushiOrginLength  = $('.sushi_roll.origin .sushi_item').length;
                var $sushiCloneLength  = $('.sushi_roll.clone .sushi_item').length;

                $('.sushi_roll.clone').css({ 
                    "width"  : $sushiOrginLength*$sushiWidth,
                    "height" : $sushiHeight 
                });
            }

            if(originNumber>=2){
                originNumber=0;
            }

            animateLoop();

        }

    });
}



 animateLoop();
```

[**jsFiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/xcg3xtsq/2/)

Here is another simplify version.
When the animation almost end, when i click the stop me and start me again, the animation become extrame slow, i know tat was a duration issue. Anyone got any idea how to solve this?

[**jsFiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/poxxz4hu/)

Comment: It's hard to visualise the issue, could you show us a working example in a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: (Continuing with @RoryMcCrossan 's) or in Stackoverflow's **Snippet**.

Comment: here you go, the one I created in jsfiddle is simplify version. https://jsfiddle.net/xcg3xtsq/2/

Comment: sorry for my bad english, I did tried clearQueue and stop, but once I callback the animate again, the animation actually taking the previous duration but not continue it. did you have any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've mentioned, the problem is that the duration for reaching the target is 3 seconds. Meaning, how closer the box is to the target, the slower it will go.

One work around is to set the duration according to the remaining distance. Using the second example:

```
var $box = $('.box');
var target = 300, defaultDuration = 3000, startX = $box.position().left;

function animateLoop(duration){
    var x = $box.position().left - startX;
  var duration = ((target - x) / target ) * defaultDuration; 
    $box.animate({ "left": 300}, {
    duration:duration,
    complete: function(){
        $box.css({'left':0});
        animateLoop();    } 
   });
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/poxxz4hu/1/)

PS, for a more linear motion when (re)starting the animation, you can set the `easing` to `linear` : [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/poxxz4hu/2/)

Comment: Thanks bro, you are so awesome :)